# Usage of python function

Tags: python

I'm a new learner of python/programming. Here is a question on top of head about the use of function in python.

If I had a list called myList.

- (a) If I were to sort it, I would use `myList.sort()`
- (b) If I were to sort it temporarily, I would use `sorted(myList)`

Note the difference between the use of two functions, one is to apply the function to `myList`, the other one is use `myList` as a parameter to the function.

My question is, each time when I use a function.

- How do I know if the function should be used as an "action" to be applied to an object (in (a)), or
- should an object passed to the function as a parameter,(in (b)).

I have been confused with this for quite long time. appreciate any explanations.

Thanks.

Comment: Read the documentation for the function.

Comment: `myList.sort()` is a method, but `sorted(myList)` is a function

Comment: `list.sort` and `sorted` are two entirely different things. One is a method, the other a builtin function. It's not like any function can be used either as `foo(x)` or `x.foo()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) is a function - [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) is a method of the `list` type.

Functions such as `sorted` are applicable to more than a specific type. For example, you can get a sorted `list`, `set`, or even a temporary generator. Only the *output* is concrete (you always get a new `list`) but not the input.

Methods such as `sort` are applicable only to the type that holds them. For example, there is a `list.sort` method but not a `dict.sort` method. Even for types whose methods have the same name, switching them is not sensible - for example, `set.copy` cannot be used to copy a `dict`.

An easy way to distinguish the two is that functions live in regular namespaces, such as modules. On the other hand, methods only live inside classes and their instances.

```
sorted     # function
list.sort  # method

import math
math.sqrt                # function
math.pi.as_integer_ratio # method
```

Conventionally, Python usually uses functions for immutable actions and methods for mutating actions. For example, `sorted` provides a *new* sorted list leaving the old one untouched; `my_list.sort()` sorts the existing list, providing no new one.

```
my_list = [4, 2, 3, 1]
print(sorted(my_list))  # prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(my_list)          # prints [4, 2, 3, 1] - unchanged by sorted
print(my_list.sort())   # prints None - no new list produced
print(my_list)          # prints [1, 2, 3, 4] - changed by sort
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two big differences between list.sort and sorted(list)

1. The list.sort() sorts the list in-place, which means it modifies the
   list. The sorted function does not modify original list but returns
   a sorted list
2. The list.sort() only applies to list (it is a method), but sorted built-in function can take any iterable object.

Please go through this [useful documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` is an in-place function whereas `sorted()` will return a sorted list, but will not alter your variable in place.  The following demonstrates the difference:

```
l = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]
l.sort()
print(l) --returns [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

l = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]
new_l = sorted(l) 
print(new_l) -- returns [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
print(l) -- [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]
```

If you want to maintain the original order of your list use `sorted`, otherwise you can use `sort()`.